# Permission denied on mount via ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, ipv6, mount

There is a ubuntu machine with these addresses

```
root@soup:/# ifconfig eth1
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:09:90:1c
      inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c/64 Scope:Link
```

I have a folder which is to be exported and then mounted `/home/wat/ipv6/`, so 
I have the corresponding `/etc/exports` configured

```
/home/wat/ipv6 [fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c](rw,sync,fsid=0,subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/home/wat/ipv6 192.168.56.101(rw,sync,fsid=0,subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

one via ipv4 and another via ipv6.

Also I have a `/etc/fstab` configured to mount these exports

```
[fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c%eth1]:/ /mnt/ip6 nfs  defaults  0 0
192.168.56.101:/ /mnt/ip4/ nfs  defaults  0 0
```

So when I run

```
root@soup:/# exportfs -rv
exporting 192.168.56.101:/home/wat/ipv6
exporting [fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c]:/home/wat/ipv6
```

and then when I try to mount them I run into

```
root@soup:/# mount -av
mount: 192.168.56.101:/ already mounted on /mnt/ip4/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Nov  9 14:44:30 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c%eth1,clientaddr=fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting [fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c%eth1]:/
```

and only the ipv4 export is mounted, do you have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: have you open ipv6 port for nfs ?

Comment: you mean these ?  
    `root@soup:/home/wat# nmap -6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c   `  
    `Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-09 16:50 EET`  
    `Nmap scan report for ubuntu1 (fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c)`  
`Host is up (0.00037s latency).`  
`Not shown: 997 closed ports`  
`PORT     STATE SERVICE`  
`22/tcp   open  ssh`  
`111/tcp  open  rpcbind`  
`2049/tcp open  nfs`

Comment: Wild guess, but you have an IPv6 link-local in `/etc/exports` that doesn't have a scope-id. You might have to add `%eth1` there.

Comment: @SanderSteffann That sounds plausible. Though it would be possible to have an implementation where a link-local address in `/etc/exports` would automatically be valid for all interfaces, it would seem like a security problem. So it would make more sense if a scope is required for link-local addresses in `/etc/exports`.

Comment: well, I specified now in `/etc/exports` to be `exporting [fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c%eth1]:/home/wat/ipv6`. Still getting the same `mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied` error.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your IPv6 addresses, run on the NFS client:

```sh
COLORFGBG=";0" ip -c a
```

You will probably see a bunch of IP-addresses with "scope global temporary dynamic". They came from IPv6 privacy extensions.

Next, check logs of your NFS-server, for example by

```sh
sudo tail -F /var/log/messages /var/log/*.log
```

I'm sure you will see your NFS client is trying to use one of the IPv6 addresses which you didn't expect.

Then use this advice [how to specify ipv6-address to use while mounting nfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/841976/) :

```
[fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c%eth1]:/ /mnt/ip6 nfs  defaults,clientaddr=fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:901c  0 0
```

P.S.: At home, to point NFS mounts, I use addresses not from fe80::/10, but from fc00::/7 (fc00…fdff): they don't need to specify Ethernet interface link name with "%eth0". If you use OpenWRT router, you can set this prefix with "IPv6 ULA-prefix" setting.